# Getting error while opening html file on window.open() in appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

we have created google docs add-in. We want to implement popout chat feature on sidebar of addon. For that we are using window.open().But when we try to open HTML file with window.open('popout.html') , we are getting error as :
Error we are getting while using popoutWindow.html :

> An error occurred in Google Docs. Please try reloading the page. If that doesn't help, please wait a few minutes.
> For more information about Google Docs editors, see Help.
> We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> - Your Google Docs team

We want to popout our existing chat of sidebar into new window with button click

Comment: `window.open` accepts a url link. I don't think it can reach `popout.html`